# Discord.py returning false when comparing two equal emojis

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make the code do something when a specific emoji is reacted to a message. I checked the message_id and they are equal however it keeps returning false for the comparison of the emojis.

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    print(payload.emoji)
    print(payload.emoji == '️')
    if payload.message_id == 829497764290625576 and payload.emoji == '️':
        print("yay")
```

this is the output:

```
️
False
```

Why is this not returning True and how do I fix the error?

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer to my question:

The types where not the same payload.emoji is a <class 'discord.partial_emoji.PartialEmoji'> type and the ️ is a str type. Changing the code to str(payload.emoji) == '️' fixed the issue.